# ASP.NET MVC Attribute routing: NullReferenceException on specific controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

I'm working on a MVC project with several controllers that used to route with default RouteConfig, i.e. `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"`.
Now the project leader wants to implement custom routes. I decided to use Attribute Routing because I used that on another small project which only had one controller.

I prefixed the HomeController and the AccountController and all the actions have Routing attributes now. This is working fine for Home and Account Controller. But I have another controller which I called PaymentController. Somehow, this controller cannot be reached with attribute routing. I tried prefixing and not prefixing the whole controller. What I think is the most strange thing is that it's throwing a NullReferenceException in `System.Web.Mvc.Routing.DirectRouteCandidate.CreateAmbiguousMatchList`.

I used the `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in RegisterRoutes, obviously, since the routing for the other two controllers works fine. Before adding the attributes in my payment controller, the default routing worked fine as well.
Do I have to configure anything else, did I forget something? Has anyone ever experienced a NullReferenceException in AttributeRouting? Is there a way to debug routing? I tried glimpse but since the routing is not successful it doesn't show anything.

Thanks in advance for your help.

edit:
As stated above, the controller is reached with default routing, so no nulref in the controller. I think the exception happens in

```
'System.Web.Mvc.Routing.DirectRouteCandidate.SelectBestCandidate'
```

Comment: First thing to check if you can get to that controller with general (non-attribute) routing. I suspect your controller can't be created because the nul-ref-exception  happens when your controller is constructed.

Comment: please provide route config and routes attributes on PaymentController

Comment: Can you add the exception stacktrace?

Comment: add your controller and show us the custom routing

Comment: This can occur when you have two custom action routes defined exactly the same